# How to sort numpy array by absolute value of a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

What I have now:

```
import numpy as np
# 1) Read CSV with headers
data = np.genfromtxt("big.csv", delimiter=',', names=True)
# 2) Get absolute values for column in a new ndarray
new_ndarray = np.absolute(data["target_column_name"])
# 3) Append column in new_ndarray to data
# I'm having trouble here. Can't get hstack, concatenate, append, etc; to work
# 4) Sort by new column and obtain a new ndarray
data.sort(order="target_column_name_abs")
```

I would like:

- A solution for 3): To be able to add this new "abs" column to the original ndarray or
- Another approach to be able to sort a csv file by the absolute values of a column.

Comment: The reason it not working is the shapes are different. Try new_ndarray.shape() and compare to ata["target_column_name"].shape()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.
First, let's create a sample array:

```
In [39]: a = (np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3) - 6)

In [40]: a
Out[40]: 
array([[-6, -5, -4],
       [-3, -2, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
```

Ok, lets say

```
In [41]: col = 1
```

which is the column we want to sort by,
and here is the sorting code - using Python's `sorted`:

```
In [42]: b = sorted(a, key=lambda row: np.abs(row[col]))
```

Let's convert b from list to array, and we have:

```
In [43]: np.array(b)
Out[43]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [-3, -2, -1],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [-6, -5, -4]])
```

Which is the array with the rows sorted according to
the absolute value of column 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
In [117]: import pandas as pd

In [118]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

In [119]: df
Out[119]: 
   a  b
0  1 -3
1  2  2
2  3 -1
3  4  4

In [120]: df['c'] = abs(df['b'])

In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
   a  b  c
0  1 -3  3
1  2  2  2
2  3 -1  1
3  4  4  4

In [122]: df.sort_values(by='c')
Out[122]: 
   a  b  c
2  3 -1  1
1  2  2  2
0  1 -3  3
3  4  4  4
```